# HAVING clause: at least one of the ungrouped values is X

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Example table:

```
Col1 | Col2
A    | Apple
A    | Banana
B    | Apple
C    | Banana
```

Output:

```
A
```

I want to get all values of `Col1` which have more than one entry and at least one with `Banana`.

I tried to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING count(*) > 1
AND ??? some kind of ONEOF(Col2) = 'Banana'
```

How to rephrase the `HAVING` clause that my query works?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col2) > 1 AND 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN col2 = 'Banana' THEN 1 END) >= 1
```

You can conditionally check for `Col1` groups having *at least one* `'Banana'` value using `COUNT` with `CASE` expression inside it.

Please note that the first `COUNT` has to use `DISTINCT`, so that groups with at least two *different* `Col1` values are detected. If by *having more than one entry* you mean also rows having the same `Col2` values repeated more than one time, then you can skip `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Col1
FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING count(*) > 1
AND Col1 in (select distinct Col1 from Table where Col2 = 'Banana');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM table
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN col2= 'Banana' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare @t table(Col1 varchar(20), Col2 varchar(20))
insert into @t values('A','Apple')
,('A','Banana'),('B','Apple'),('C','Banana')

select col1 from @t A
where exists
(select col1 from @t B where a.col1=b.col1 and b.Col2='Banana')
group by col1
having count(*)>1
```